# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Slow wifi speed Intel Centrino N-100

Tags: networking, intel-wireless

I have an issue in my laptop. I can't get a decent internet speed via wifi. I can get about 5Mbps. Meanwhile on Windows I have 50-60Mbps. What should I do? My previous netbook didn't have that issue, but I have to use this laptop with Intel Centrino N-100 since the netbook is broken.